# Postgres: Create objects in another database without connecting to it

Tags: postgresql

I've a postgres setup with below configs:

- Super User: postgres
- Database 1: postgres
- Database 2: app_db (not yet created)

My liquibase script connects to the postgres DB using postgres user and creates 'app_db' and users that have DDL permissions on the app_db.

Now, I want to create Extension in app_db using postgres user in the same connection (without really connecting to app_db Database).

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: It would also be a security issue when it would be possible to change something in a database without any connection.

Comment: If you want to do this sort of thing you would need to do `CREATE DATABASE app_db WTH TEMPLATE=some_template_db` where `some_template_db` already has the extension installed. For more info see [CREATE DATABASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Will try them out.